# Running two threads at the same time is causing a hardfault

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded, freertos

So i'm learning FreeRTOS on STM32 and currently following a tutorial to get things started. Following are my concerns with the first one being the most:

- I have two threads, but upon running a scheduler, I see a hardfault. But when I run a single thread, I see no issues. I initially thought it'd be related to the stack size but each thread is taking up `130 * 4 = 520 bytes`.
- Does stack size refer to the word size in the context of rtos? [(if the stack is 16-bits wide and usStackDepth is 100, then 200 bytes will be allocated for use as the task’s stack)](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html)
- `TaskHandle_t` is a pointer to `struct tskTaskControlBlock`. Then why is the address of the `xTaskBlinky` passed to the last parameter of `xTaskCreate()`, which takes `TaskHandle_t * const pxCreatedTask )`?

  ```
   typedef struct tskTaskControlBlock* TaskHandle_t; // in task.h

   // main.c

   TaskHandle_t xTaskBlinky = NULL;
   TaskHandle_t xTaskBlinky1 = NULL;

   void vTask1_Handler(void *params);
   void vTask2_Handler(void *params);

   void SystemClock_Config(void);

   int main(void)
   {
       /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

       /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
       HAL_Init();

       /* Configure the system clock */
       SystemClock_Config();

       xTaskCreate(vTask1_Handler, "Blinky", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 2, &xTaskBlinky);
       xTaskCreate(vTask2_Handler, "Blinky1", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 2, &xTaskBlinky1);

       vTaskStartScheduler();
       while (1);
   }

   void vTask1_Handler(void *params)
   {
       while(1);
   }

   void vTask2_Handler(void *params)
   {
       while(1);
   }
  ```

  And the program goes into the infinite loop upon running a scheduler:

  ```
    * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an 
    *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
    *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
    * @param  None     
    * @retval None       
   */
       .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
   Default_Handler:
   Infinite_Loop:
     b  Infinite_Loop
     .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
  ```

Comment: I don't know anything about FreeRTOS, but I routinely write embedded O/S's. I am not entirely sure what you are asking. But I did find a "kind of" question in there which I think I can handle: "why is the address of the xTaskBlinky passed to the last parameter of xTaskCreate()?" Two possible answers: (1) They may need to modify the handle. If so, they need a way to access it. (2) They may use a concept called "memory marking." This is helpful during O/S resets. Again, if so, they would need access to the handle.

Comment: but passing `&` of a pointer would be apt for an argument of type `**`, no?

Comment: also not sure what's unclear about my question. if you could point out, I can edit it...

Comment: You need to examine the return value from xTaskCreate, I'm guessing the task creation are failing and you are throwing away the return value telling you why.

Comment: @Pokloha Yes and no. If the handle itself is already a pointer type (typedef'd for example) then you'd use a single * to refer to a pointer to it. Internally, the compiler knows what's going on. You are just asking a syntax question, though. If I say "typedef char * x_t;" and then want a pointer to one of those, I'd still write "x_t *" and not "x_t **". That's for the compiler to worry over. Not you. It is a "char **" but since you aren't writing that way you don't use two asterisks.

Comment: @Pokloha It's all unclear to me except what I called out to you. And even then, I'm not certain it was clear to me. I've been doing embedded C programming since 1978 when I was working on the Unix v6 kernel code and embedded assembly coding for four years before that. And I can definitely say I'm confused by your writing. (I don't have an answer about stack size -- you'd need to read the doc on that. It's a simple question left to people familiar with the details. A stack is usually carved out of heap space, though not necessarily so.)

Comment: @RonBeyer the return value is 1. For some reason eclispe isn't helping me find out the definition of `pdPASS` and other variables that store into `xReturn`. Just checked in the RM and `pdPASS` is 1. So that seems okay?

Comment: Assuming you're using a decent debugger, look at the value in your SCB->VECTACTIVE and/or NVIC->IABRx (or similar) registers to see exactly *which interrupt* is triggering and not being handled.

Comment: @brhans all IABRx are 0

Comment: Ok - that that means it's none of the peripherals. What about SCB->VECTACTIVE? That covers Hard/Bus/Mem-Faults, NMI, etc too which the NVIC doesn't.

Comment: which one are you exactly referring to? https://imgur.com/a/mx0j9OD

Comment: @jonk i'm prolly missing something but this is how i'm visualizing it: https://cplayground.com/?p=cassowary-termite-rhinoceros

Comment: @Pokloha Looks like the syntax would compile to me. It's not exactly good coding practice as you've exposed the typedef's meaning all over the place. The typedef should be opaque to consumers. But it should compile, I'd imagine.

Comment: the code was an example to what I meant and what the code I posted here is doing, hence my question about passing `&` and not just a pointer

Comment: Sorry - VECTACTIVE is the lower bits in SCB->ICSR, so in your case `3`: HardFault. Typically happens when you try to access a non-existent memory location.

Comment: Got it. But how come including two threads causes a hardfault but including one doesn't?

Comment: Does FreeRTOS update your `xTaskBlinky` and `xTaskBlinky1` with valid pointer values after the `xTaskCreate` calls? Exactly which STM32 are you using?

Comment: @brhans looks like it: https://imgur.com/nW030zG, and STM32F401RE. Also it could really be related to any of the parameters in `FreeRTOSConfig.h`

Comment: regarding; `typedef struct tskTaskControlBlock* TaskHandle_t;`  it is a very poor programming practice to hide a pointer in a `typedef` statement.  Such hiding  in misunderstanding when (much later) you (or anyone else) is looking at the code

Comment: that's the kernel code and not mines @user3629249